# Tecnologies required to intercept hypersonic missile

Tags: nuclear-war

In the endless arms race between weapon and countermeasures, it strikes me particularly the mitigation for hyper-sonic missiles (which can be nuclear weapons).

I have come up with carbon nanotubes as a necessary precursor to take them down. That's because you could build a bigger scale of a [missile based trap net](https://www.unmannedairspace.info/latest-news-and-information/russias-federal-nuclear-center-develops-missile-based-net-capture-c-uas-system/). However is hard for me to do any calculations on the forces at play to decide if this is realistic or not. I could only find that, by diameter, it's 100x stronger, I assume tensile strength.

Is there any source (fictional or not) that talks about this? If there is some other possible method, even with future tech, I would like to avoid doing the calculations here.

Comment: Clarifying: you are asking how strong a net must be to catch a hypersonic missile?

Comment: I would be amazed if it's possible to catch a hypersonic missile--the energies involved will break things, not result in a catch.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm more concerned with constructing a continent-sized net that is 45 miles tall, and how it might affect sunlight reaching the crops below...

Comment: @LorenPechtel well you don't need a catch, damaging it could easily compromise yield or even disable the trigger mechanism. Also the pressure of the missile on the net would be in the ~1000TPa which is only 10 times the tensile strength of an individual shell of carbon nanotubes.

Comment: The net-based capture system is for _drones_, and copter-style drones, at that.  I don't think it's remotely applicable to capturing missiles.

Comment: Hypersonic missiles are their own worst enemy. One flaw and they fly themselves to pieces through wind resistance. Detecting a low altitude hypersonic cruise missile and shooting at it fast enough is hard. But once you have shot it, it almost doesn't matter what you shoot it with or how hard: the missile was already on the verge of self-obliteration. Throw a nail into the air and if a missile hits it at mach 7, it will rip itself into pieces.

Comment: @JamieB this would be a great research starting point. do you have any sources?

Answer (score 4):

Lets say im your opponent in this world. You build your net, and have spent your resources on it.

What would I do? Just admit defeat like 'nope, cant fly there, there is a net'? No, I wont do that.

What I would do instead is fly above the net. Hypersonic speed is likely enough to jump over 45 miles even if engine is air breathing, using inertia.

Or I would send fifth of my missiles slightly ahead and let it explode, destroying pillars that holds the net. Since hight is about equal to pillar distance, and hight is 45 miles, you would also need similarly spaced pillars. Be it unbelievable amount of superalloy, or a flimsy but even more expensive set of airships.

Or I would be pragmatic and planning far ahead. And I would smash some of my missiles in your net on purpose, to let you sink deeper in your belief that this is a meaningful way to spend resources. While your net would only slowdown missile group by about 10 seconds, needed for a blast of the first wave of missiles to disperse so that further waves come through, amount of resources needed for such a net would be equal to a million missiles. Enough to blow up your net, and all of your missiles that you could've had to launch, and even using nukes as anti-missiles, since my advantage in number of missiles will be so extreme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think it's unrelated to my question. I was talking about missile based trap nets. You seem to be talking about a static net?

Comment: @gurghet at some point there was a mention of 45 miles. This is too big to be moving thing. And too small for anti-missile missile range, that can travel much longer distance. So yes, I assumed a static net. If you mean a rocket that launches a net, then it range of action will be less than a shrapnel based anti-missile, and much less than nuke-based anti-missile. If you want to use shorter action range, you should worry about precision of navigating your anti-missiles. That wasnt mentioned